# iCarousel data source not called

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, icarousel

So, I'm using the `iCarousel` framework in iOS. I've created it and called several methods on it, and in the simulator, when I swipe in the area that it is supposed to be, it performs the appropriate `NSLog`. So I know that my iCarousel was properly created and initialized.

The only problem is that the `dataSource` method is never being called. I even did:

```
self.myCarousel.dataSource = self;
    self.myCarousel.delegate =self;
```

In my `viewDidLoad`, but they are not being called

Please help!

EDIT: SOLVED!

Comment: Have you tried [self.myCarousel reloadData];?

Comment: [self.carousel reload];try this

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. Didn't solve my problem, but I found the issue. I will update in a minute.

Comment: @user3702835 Stackoverflow is not a forum. If you have solved your problem, post an answer and accept it.

Comment: Ok, I shall. Thanks. I just feel really stupid because I was searching for a solution, couldn't find it, posted here, then 2 mins later figured it out

Comment: I can't add an answer. Will someone please paste this answer: My `- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel` method was returning `0` for some reason, so the images were not used.   This was because my array count was returning `0` for some reason.   Anyway, this issue has been solved by editing my `- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel` to return a "magic number".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel` method was returning `0` for some reason, so the images were not used.

This was because my array count was returning `0` for some reason.

Anyway, this issue has been solved by editing my `- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel` to return a "magic number".